# htaccess + redirect users depending on the browser language

Tags: .htaccess

I was reading all questions related to this topic and I couldn't find anything.

First, I have this domain: www.example.com

My purpose is to redirect users depending on the language of the browser:

ex:     www.example.com   =>   www.example.com/es
        www.example.com   =>   www.example.com/en

I followed this rule but here is not the source url:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^*\.domain\.com.ar/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/es / [L,R] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^*\.domain\.be/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/en / [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In this piece of code, where is establish the destination website? I mean...   IF the user wants to reach this site: www.example.com and I need to redirect him to www.example.com/es or www.example.com/en depending on the language of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check domain and browser language, this is what you could do:

```
# Check domain (1), browser language (2) and redirect to subdirectory (3)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/ [L,R=301]

# ... copy block above for other languages ...

# Fallback for any other language to spanish
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/es/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

> In this piece of code, where is establish the destination website?

Here:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/es / [L,R]
```

and here:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/en / [L,R]
```

No idea if that's a typo or if this is what you have in your htaccess file, but this will produce 500 internal server errors because you are giving `RewriteRule` 4 parameters, when it only wants either 2 or 3.

The other problem is with your `%{HTTP_REFERER}` regular expression. Apache's probably going to puke here: `^*\.domain\.com.ar/`, you probably meant: `^[^/]*\.domain\.com.ar/` or something. So you probably want your rules to look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^[^/]*\.domain\.com.ar/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/es/ [L,R] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^[^/]*\.domain\.be/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/en/ [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Of course, you'd be replacing the instances of `domain.com.ar` and `domain.be` and `www.example.com` with the correct hostnames.

Also note: the `Accept-Language` header is a complicated string of qualifiers. It isn't as simple as an `en` or `es`. A spanish webbrowser could contain both an `en` and  `es` simply because both are supported languages. Determining an exact language to redirect to based on this header isn't really in the scope of mod_rewrite and htaccess.

Comment: but if the user enter in the browser: www.example.com, I want to redirect the user to: www.example.com/es or www.example.com/en. The code provided above is not working