# PHP subdomain redirect according to language variable

Tags: php, redirect, http-redirect

I'm trying to write a **php script** that **checks** the language(which is defined by the language function in **$language**) for a value and if user **requests any address, [www.example.com/foo/bar/data.php?=foobar](http://www.example.com/foo/bar/data.php?=foobar) it will redirect him by **http refresh or redirect**** or header location(not preferable) **to subdomain.example.com/$1 ($1 as in the same original requested address).**

something like this but without the header location:

```
<?php if ($language == "en") { header ("Location: http://"$language".example.com/"$1""); } ?>
```

this does not work, also I get an error in the log "header already sent by another file" which is another script I got running and cannot change the code.

So, what I need is a script that reads the variable and according to its value it will redirect the user to the appropriate subdomain.

Comment: If its saying headers already sent... then make sure that there isn't any output (such as php's `echo`). Also make sure there aren't any new lines at the end of your `?>` tags.

Comment: its already sent by another script file but if cant rewrite that one, it as to stay as it is.

Comment: Since your title mentions .htaccess why not just use the .htaccess file to check the users browser's accept-language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612707/htaccess-redirect-users-depending-on-the-browser-language and do a redirect accordingly, or are you doing something to let them choose some other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can echo a `javascript` code that contains redirection. Try this one.

```
<?php
    if($language === "en"){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'http://' . $language . '.example.com/' . $1; </script>";
    }
?>
```

This code works most for me compared to `header('Location: etc...')`.

Comment: good thinking! this works for mim better than http refresh or header location

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // Language detection code
    // ...

    if ('en' === $language)
    {
        header('Location: http://' . $language . '.example.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit();
    }
```

If you really can't change the code from the other file, you'll need to make an html redirection instead.

```
<?php
    // Language detection code
    // ...

    if ('en' === $language)
    {
        $url = 'http://' . $language . '.example.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        echo <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url={$url}" />
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
EOF;
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your help.

So i tested this out(included it in a header file), and it seems to work, execept for the refresh part..it stays in infinite loop.
So i think it need a condition like  is subdomains differs from www. then ignore the redirect, in order to stop.